# How to develop a function called `setOption`?

Tags: r, variadic-functions, getter-setter, setter, variadic

`R::base` has a function called `getOption` that works as expected.

```
getOption("max.print");
```

I can't find the inverse function `setOption`.  Please let me know where it is?

If it doesn't exist, can we write one?

```
setOption("max.print", 20);
```

where the function is in skeleton form:

```
setOption = function(myKey, myValue)
    {
    
    
    }
```

I tried the obvious:

```
options()[["max.print"]] = 20
```

which throws an error.

Maybe something with:

```
onames = names(options());
options(setNames( ???
```

The above code is unfinished, hence this question.

Here is an example of a `variadic getter-setter` function for the "par":

```
setParKey = function(myKey, myValue)
    {
    pnames = names( par(no.readonly = TRUE) );
    if(is.element(myKey, pnames))
        {
        par(setNames(list(myValue), myKey))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does `utils::setOption()` give you what you want?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for `options(max.print = 20)`?

Comment: `??utils::setOption` doesn't show anything

Comment: @mshaffer my apologies, it is `R.utils::setOption()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setOption <- options
setOption(max.print = 20)
getOption("max.print")
#> [1] 20
```

or closer to your interface (using R package rlang):

```
setOption <- function(myKey, myValue) rlang::exec('options', !!myKey := myValue)
setOption('max.print', 30)
getOption("max.print")
#> [1] 30
```

I am not sure I understand your point about variadic functions, but the function `options()` is already variadic...

```
setOptions <- options
setOptions(max.print = 20, digits = 12)
getOption("max.print")
#> [1] 20
getOption("digits")
#> [1] 12
```

Comment: This is the obvious solution, not what I am looking for.  Looking for a `variadic` solution using the programming concept of `getter-setter`.  That is a function `setOption` that variadically passes a key and a value.

Comment: can you provide an example of what such variadic function call would look like?

Comment: Sure, I will post a working example of a `variadic getter-setter`

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for a `R::base` solution.  After fiddling around with the example for `par`, I figured this out.

```
setOption = function(myKey, myValue)
    {
    onames = names( options() );
    if(is.element(myKey, onames))
        {
        options(setNames(list(myValue), myKey));
        }
    }
```

This follows the `variadic getter-setter` approach.  It also creates the obvious missing `inverse` function of `base::getOption`.

#### Example

```
getOption("digits");
# [1] 3
setOption("digits", 5);
getOption("digits");
# [1] 5
```